# Docusign ReplyEmailAddressOverride setting, does it require a ReplyNameOverride as well?

Tags: docusignapi

If you use the properties in EmailSettings to change the reply email address, do you also need to assign a value to the reply name override property? If you don't, what does it use for the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [legacy official REST documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Add%20Email%20Setting%20Overrides%20to%20an%20Envelope.htm), the `replyEmailNameOverride` is **NOT** required.

While the documentation doesn't mention this, if you don't specify it, it seems that it will reuse the name of the original recipient it was sent to.
See my example below in C#:

```
EmailSettings settings = new EmailSettings
{
    ReplyEmailAddressOverride = "otherUserThanTheSende@fakeemail.com"
};

docuSignEnvelope.EmailSettings = settings;
```

[image]

To go further, if you look at the DocuSign recipient email source, you can see that they assign the recipient name to the reply email as below :

[image]

Comment: Ok. So if no name is supplied, it uses the original recipients name. Did not expect that behavior. But good to know. Thank you.

Comment: Not very intuitive behavior I agree.